# C ++ lambda captures local variables like parameter names

Tags: c++, lambda

```
int a = 3;
auto f = [a] (int a) { return a > a; }
```

Q：capture the local variable names `a` and lambda have a differentiated method?

I think it is within the scope of a parametric `a` is independent of the external local variables `a`, would like to know whether there is something like this pointer distinction.

Answer (score 3):

When the compiler processes a lambda, what it does is basically create a special class that it instantiates. The actual lambda function becomes a `operator()` function, and the captured variables becomes member variables in this special class.

That means the normal scoping rules apply, where local variables and arguments shadows member variables.

So in your case `a` is the argument, not the captured variable.